# What does an if look like in IL?

Tags: c#, if-statement, definition, intermediate-language

What does an `if` statement look like when it's compiled into IL?

It's a very simple construct in C#. Can sombody give me a more abstract definition of what it really is?

Comment: You can check this using `ildasm.exe` from a Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: It's a very simple construct, period. I don't know in IL, but in assembly code, you perform a comparison and then a branch. Very simple in asm, so one has to assume it's just as simple in a high level language.

Comment: Your question is answered by the statement of this question from earlier today.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659093/ms-c-compiler-and-non-optimized-code/3660295#3660295

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a few `if` statements and how they translate to IL:

```
ldc.i4.s 0x2f                      var i = 47;
stloc.0 

ldloc.0                            if (i == 47)
ldc.i4.s 0x2f
bne.un.s L_0012

ldstr "forty-seven!"                   Console.WriteLine("forty-seven!");
call Console::WriteLine

L_0012:
ldloc.0                            if (i > 0)
ldc.i4.0 
ble.s L_0020

ldstr "greater than zero!"             Console.WriteLine("greater than zero!");
call Console::WriteLine

L_0020:
ldloc.0                            bool b = (i != 0);
ldc.i4.0 
ceq 
ldc.i4.0 
ceq 
stloc.1 

ldloc.1                            if (b)
brfalse.s L_0035

ldstr "boolean true!"                  Console.WriteLine("boolean true!");
call Console::WriteLine

L_0035:
ret
```

One thing to note here: The IL instructions are always the “opposite”. `if (i > 0)` translates to something that effectively means “if `i <= 0`, then jump over the body of the `if` block”.

Comment: Is there a copy-paste error in the chunk starting with L_0020: repeating  ltc.i4.0 then ceq?

Comment: @AndyDent No, this is the exact output of the compiler. You can argue that it could be written shorter, but if you just remove one `ldc.i4.0` + `ceq`, the meaning would change: it would then mean `i == 0` instead of `i != 0`.

Comment: got it! (I think), in long form, that IL is equivalent to b = ((i==0) == 0)

Answer (score 5):

A branch instruction is used that will jump to a target instruction depending on the value(s) on top of the stack.

```
brfalse Branch to target if value is zero (false)
brtrue  Branch to target if value is non-zero (true)
beq     Branch to target if equal
bge     Branch to target if greater than or equal to
bgt     Branch to target if greater than
ble     Branch to target if less than or equal to
blt     Branch to target if less than
bne.un  Branch to target if unequal or unordered
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the condition of the `if`.  For example if you are checking a reference against `null` the compiler will emit a [`brfalse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brfalse.aspx) instruction (or a [`brtrue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brtrue(VS.80).aspx) depending on what you wrote).

The *actual* `if` condition will differ based on the condition itself but a dissasembler like `ILDASM` or Reflector would be a better tool for learning more.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example:

```
ldloc.1                    // loads first local variable to stack
ldc.i4.0                   // loads constant 0 to stack
beq                        // branch if equal
```

This would be equal to

```
if(i == 0) //if i is the first local variable
```

Other ifs would differ, including conditional branches. This really is too much to explain in one post, you are better of looking for an introduction to IL-Code.

There is a nice article on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/ilassembly.aspx) concerning this.

Comment: `ldloc.1` loads the second local variable. ☺ Also, in your example `if` translates to `beq`, not `ceq`.

Comment: ldloc.0 usually is the local class. you are right with beq of course.