# System.Reflection.Emit - If Statement Generation

Tags: c#, reflection, compiler-construction, clr, il

I'm trying to learn how `If` statements are generated with ILGenerator in C#.

Here's my code: (ilg is an ILGenerator)

```
ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
Label start = ilg.DefineLabel();
ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse, start);
ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello");
ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
ilg.MarkLabel(start);
```

Some notes:

- Alone, calling Console.WriteLine works perfectly.
- This is the error that I get when I run the generated exe:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program. at Testing.Test.Main(String[] )

Comment: Related: [What does an if look like in IL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663438/what-does-an-if-look-like-in-il)

Comment: @SplittyDev thanks for edit :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code works almost fine, you just forgot to put `OpCodes.Ret` at end, see the code that works:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("PrintHello", typeof(void), null);
    var ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
    var toEnd = ilGenerator.DefineLabel();
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse, toEnd);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello");
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
    ilGenerator.MarkLabel(toEnd);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var @delegate = (Action)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
    @delegate();
}
```

Then you'll have this output

> Hello

If you comment this line `ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);` you will get this exception

> `System.InvalidProgramException`: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

#### Remember, every method in C# must have the **OpCode.Ret**

If your Main method is empty, like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

#### The IL generated (in debug mode, without optimization) will be this

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main (string[] args) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 2 (0x2)
    .maxstack 8
    .entrypoint

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

#### The IL generated (in release mode, **with** optimization) will be this

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main (string[] args) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 1 (0x1)
    .maxstack 8
    .entrypoint

    IL_0000: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Works flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks @DaniloLekovic I am glad that this answer was useful to you.