# How optimized is the C# compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, compiler-optimization, cil

The IL code (generated with https://dotnetfiddle.net) of this piece of code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 10;
        if (i < 4)
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

contains ldstr "Hello World".

Shouldn't the compiler know that Console.WriteLine never gets executed?

The IL code of this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (10 < 4)
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

doesn't contain the ldstr command.

Now i'm confused.. is the .NET compiler really that stupid?
The C#/IL code of both examples do exactly the same: nothing. But the IL code of the first example is larger than the other. Shouldn't a good compiler just call the constructor and do nothing..?

Edit:

Yes i already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659093/ms-c-sharp-compiler-and-non-optimized-code) but i'm not talking about additional generated locals.

If `i` would be a propertie or a public variable, it would possible to modify it from another thread. But `i` only exists in Main()...

Comment: Did you try with optimisation on and off? Debug/Release mode.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: After turning max optimization and Release mode, take a look what code does JIT generate. That would be interesting.

Comment: If you use your first code snippet in a debugger it is possible to stop right after `int i = 10;` and before `if (i < 4)`. In that case it is possible for the debugger to change the value of `i` and the outcome at the if statement has to be evaluated.

Comment: Never say that a compiler is stupid. These beasts have super-human capabilities. If you look a the innumerable posts on this site claiming a compiler bug, you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That a compiler has actual bug? You're right that's rare, though it does happen. That a compiler does not optimize something the way you would expect? I think that happens much more commonly (especially since there are some "obvious" optimizations that the compiler is not allowed to perform).

Comment: @svick: compiler bugs are exceptional and much less frequent than human error (I only recall of a single one in my whole career, which turned out not to be a bug but a counter-intuitive effect of a floating-point option). Many claimed failed optimizations are due to the programmer knowing facts that are not expressed in the code (like "the input value is always positive"), or wrong reasoning. Compilers are much better than us at this game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the x64 disassembly of your snippet:

```
00007FF7C6083E0E  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
--- C:\Dev\Temp\Test\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\Program.cs --------------------------
            int i = 10;
00007FF7C6083E10  ret  
--- No source file -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which means, the JIT performed dead code elimination (`ret` = *return*, the `Main` function simply exits immediately).

The compiler only performs some basic optimizations, but the bulk of it is left to the JIT, to optimize for the platform it runs on.

Though I agree the compiler certainly could perform this optimization in this case, as it's platform-independent.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But why does int i = 10 appear in your x64 disassembly-snippet?

Comment: @michidk That's simply the source-to-assembly mapping that VS displays in order to help you find your way around the assembly code. It shows you that this line of code mapped roughly to `ret`, so the local isn't even there.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler acts as expected in my opinion. Compilers generally evaluate only constants and constant expressions, because their values are known at compile time. The variable "i" in your example and the expression "i < 4" are evaluated at run time and that is why the compiler does not optimize the code in this case.

Comment: I'd add that more likely the JIT does indeed optimize it away when generating the code for the running platform

Comment: Yes, most probably it does.

Comment: This is wrong, common compilers (say, for C++) perform constant propagation, so that code would be optimized.

Comment: @svick, you are right that compilers do propagate constants, but the value of constants is known at compile time. The "i" in the question of this thread is a variable and its value is evaluated at run time. That is why the compiler does not optimize the "if" clause in this case.

Comment: The value of the constant `10` is known at compile time. And constant propagation means that the value of `i` (which is technically not a constant, but its value is effectively constant) is also known at compile time. Look at the assembly in Lucas' answer: the JIT compiler did optimize the `if` (and any optimizing C++ compiler would do the same).

Answer (score -3):

I also think that this should not be the responsibility of the debugger. Although everything is obvious in your sample, every line shows cumulative affect while calculating values, which is a enormous workload, take it as calculating the total Chess moves available. (There are billions of more moves available in chess than the all stars in the universe.)

Comment: I don't understand anything about this answer. What does the debugger have to do with this? How is this related to chess moves? (It sounds like you're talking about combinatorial explosion, but I don't see how that would be relevant here either.)

Comment: To understand a line will be executed or not, or a variable is obsolete, the compiler or debugger have to go through every logic available in your function. This is exactly like calculating all the chess moves available.